# How are events implemented in MVP

Tags: gwt, mvp

I went through the [link](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/gwt-continuous-build-testing.html),
but there it was a bit difficult for me to understand the basic reason as to why

1. we shouldn't use `view.getSaveButton().addClickHandler()....` i.e to say why we should not have getter in our Display interface?? . What I understood from the video is that it is not a good practice to maintain views state information within the presentation, but sorry to say I didn't understood how is that gonna help us. ?
2. In that video its also mentioned that we should use `setListeners()` rather than `addListeners()`, that is to avoid more than one listener in the interface.
3. He says he is diverging from Rays understanding of MVP, with respect to not using `HasClickHandlers()` , please explain why ?

One of the reason why I couldnt understand the point could be that in that video there is lot of  Google Wave specific code, It would had been easier for me to understand had he used a more generic and a more simpler code to make us understand his point.

Please pardon me if I have offended any one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Presenter should not be depended from UI widgets - there is some reasons for it:

- Separating of UI representation in Views and application logic in Presenter
- Defined in interfaces behaviour of View and Presenter
- Easy to write Unit-tests for presenter layer
- Several views(desktop, mobile, e.t.c.) for one presenter

Simple set of interfaces named MVP allows us to separate this two layers:

```
 

// View interface 
interface View extends AsWidget {

    void setPresenter(Presenter presenter); // cross reference to presenter

    interface Presenter { // presenter must extends from this interface
        void onContactEditClick(); // callback from view handling in presenter without any UI code
    }
}
```

```
// View realization (part)
public class ViewImpl extends Composite implements View {

    @UiHandler('someButton') // or 'somelink', e.t.c.
    void onContactEditClick(ClickEvent event) {
        presenter.onContactEditClick();
    }
}
```

Presenter is isolated from controls that firing events. It can be button, can be link, e.t.c. So it is possible to create several implementations of views(for desktop and mobile platforms for example) with a different set of UI controls in each view and use this views with a one presenter.

[Google MVP](http://code.google.com/intl/en/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html)

2) Listeners are related to UI controls. In my opinion, it is better to avoid usage of listeners between view and presenter via interface methods like in Point1 sample. In fact, Presenter interface inside of View interface is a better listener for all events from view.

3) The same. HasClickHanlers related to View layer and should be separated from presenter.